# Блок разными цветами на CSS

Tags: html, css

Необходимо один div блок закрасить тремя цветами. Должен получиться квадрат 180px, как на фото. 
Общая ширина: 180px
Общая высота: 180px
Высота желтой секции: 90px
Ширина белой секции: 90px
Радиус скругления: 9px
Цвета:
черный: #0c0c0c
желтый: #f8e34b
белый: #eeedef
тень: #c8c8c8, 178 градусов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: где попытки ?....

Comment: Я могу сделать это на трех блоках или градиентом в одном. Но, если делать градиентом, то будет одна полоса с переходом слева направо. А как сделать, чтобы один цвет был вверху и два внизу я не могу понять.

Comment: @Леха в чём прикол делать на одном `div`? сделай на трёх, или svg-картинку туда присунь

Comment: можно использовать один див и два его псевдоэлемента. див весь жёлтый, а псевдоэлементы (черный и серый) поверх него

Comment: @Леха, ответ на ваш вопрос - множественный background, а для органичения размеров и позиции каждого background'а можно использовать background-size и background-position.

Comment: @КапитанФлинт, улучшаю навыки. Мне подкинули задачку, вот теперь думаю

Answer (score 2):

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  border-radius: 9px;
  background: #f8e34b;
}

.block::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background: #eeedef;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 9px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 5px #c8c8c8;
}

.block::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background: #0c0c0c;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 9px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Ну да, я это и имел в виду. Только тень не такая, как нужно - там только сверху и с наклоном (я, кстати, с ходу не могу придумать, как так сделать)

Comment: тоже наклон тени не знаю как обыграть

Comment: Нужен еще один элемент который повернут и отбрасывает тень https://codepen.io/haibnu/pen/FxGsI